# Is there any programmatical way to clear server cache in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

as a default, I will gonna cache user's profile data for 1hour, since user's profile data is most likely won't change unless user it self changes its own data.

However, When user itself changes there data, Its obvious I need to clear that specific user's cache. Since it is out-dated.

In this case, Is there any programatical way to clear next.js server cache? (like clearing next cache as event-driven way?)

Just to note, I have to fetch user's profile data on server component.